# How to extract specific values out of a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file with `keys : values` on different lines as the following:

```
2 : 1507735181462872587547461110959
2 : 11504523
2 : 17122192286591811445449345578723033763535242012314847278
5 : 129555572211450066082129946922739441
```

And I want to extract the key and the value into different variables from a line of my choosing, may it be the first line or the third.

If the chosen line is the second, then these variables are created:

```
a = 2
b = 11504523
```

But, I have no idea how I could extract the data from only one line of my choosing specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the variables as integers, you can simply parse the file and split at the `:` to get the values you want

```
choice = 2

with open('temp.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
chosen_line = lines[choice]
values = chosen_line.split(':')
a = int(values[0].strip())
b = int(values[1].strip())

print(a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('yourfile.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

a, b = lines[chosen_index].split(':')
```

This would create `str` objects in both `a` and `b`. If you need them as `int` you can convert it after that. This all assumes that `yourfile.txt` is the file you're reading, the format is exactly what you say it is, and that `chosen_index` is the line number you want (the first line is numbered `0`)